# Android webview goback() issue with ajax results

Tags: javascript, android, webview

My Webview loads a page which contains a list of items, and has a button to load more. The button loads through AJAX. When clicked on an item, it loads another page. 
The problem is when I goBack() to the list page, it shows the page as initially loaded(without the AJAX loaded pages) instead of going back to where left off (but on Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, it does go back to the previous page as it was left)

I've tried the following, but i get the same result :

```
mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );
```

How can i make it act like chrome ?

Comment: Are you  using fragment or activity

Comment: I'm using an activity

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in activity then handle `webView` back-stack then you can check using `mWebView.canGoBack()` method in your activity `onBackPressed()` method as follow -

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
          mWebView.goBack();
      } else {
         super.onBackPressed();
      }
}
```

Comment: The issue i'm facing is that, the webview seems to be loading the page again, even with webview.goBack().

Comment: Use `webChromeClient` instead of `webViewClient`